# Notepad++ plugin to copy text with line numbers

Tags: windows, gratis, notepad++

I want to be able to copy a few lines from a text file (could be a log file or a source code file) and each line should be copied with its line number.

E.g. if I copy these three lines,

[image: Screenshot]

it should NOT result in the text like usual

```
2016-10-26 09:00 ERROR Something bad happened
2016-10-26 09:00 NullPointerException!!!
2016-10-26 09:00 Shutting down
```

but as

```
Line 10 - 2016-10-26 09:00 ERROR Something bad happened
Line 11 - 2016-10-26 09:00 NullPointerException!!!
Line 12 - 2016-10-26 09:00 Shutting down
```

Ideally the text before and after the line number is configurable.